# How to make Collectors.groupingBy() return a sorted LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, java-stream

For example, I have a List:

```
{Cat, Cat, Cat, Dog, Dog, Rat}
```

I want to return a sorted Map, in ascending or descending at my choice, where the keys are the animal names, and the values are their appearance times.

For example

```
{
    Rat: 1
    Dog: 2
    Cat: 3
}
```

By using

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> map = 
    list
    .stream()                              
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

I can have a `LinkedHashMap`, but it is not sorted.

I know that I can sort the Map afterward, but is there a way to do it in one stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Sort the stream before collecting

Comment: or just use a `TreeMap` when you want to sort by key. But when you want to sort by value, there is no way around sorting afterwards, as the values are not known before having calculated all groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `sorted()` operator:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> result = Arrays.stream(array)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed.